# Is Neo4j able to import buffer objects?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import a binary uuid as an entity id but id loads as a string. I'm an thinking this has to do with storing the data in a csv file prior to loading.

I've seen neo4j accepts binaries, but not sure how it could be implemented.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///output_files/entity_file.csv' AS line
MERGE (e:Entity {id: line.ent_uuid })
```

`{"id":"{\"type\":\"Buffer\",\"data\":[205,155,117,117,97,122,78,219,15│
│0,217,94,99,158,70,112,123]}"}`

Also, if I stored the id as a regular unicode string, how much of a performance loss would there be?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV is a text file, so before importing a column into Neo4j you have to cast it.

Cypher comes with some conversion functions : `toInt`, `toFloat`, ... 
But there is none to convert a string as an array of bytes (supported by Neo4j).

On the other side, you can create your own function (called user defined functions). Take a look here : https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/

But I have never try to manage bytes in cypher.
Hope it can helps.

Cheers